# Flood It game Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, artificial-intelligence, a-star

The game link is here:
http://floodit.appspot.com/

Rules are simple, you have to choose one of the color from neighbours, start point is left-upper corner, and then color changes, and you've flooded some more area. goal is to flood whole grid.

There are some topics on stackoverflow about this game, but I can't find answer to my question. my goal is to get optimal way to flood whole grid. now I'm on this position:
[image]

I'm trying to solve this problem by A*. and my heuristics is to choose color, that minimizes distance to furthest component (int this case 2,4,1,3 with red colors on image, are furthest ones) and if several colors minimizes distance to one of the furthest components, then I choose color, which has most points in it (in this case my algorithm chooses "0", because, it minimizes distance to all of the furthest nodes and has more points in it, then "2").

My teacher gave us optimal solutions and in this case his best way is: 2, 0, 1, 4 ,3, 2, 5; which is 7 more units.
but according to my heuristics, I choose "0", and best way is: 0, 2, 4, 5, 3, 1, 0, 2, 4; which 9 more units.
Can anybody answer me, on which heuristics do I have to choose "2" in this position, and not "0"?
thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not just use brute force? There are only six colors, so if the optimal solution is of length eight, it's only 1.6M trials, which is pretty doable. Though I guess if you get hit with a solution that's longer than ten or eleven trials, you might be out of luck.

Comment: what is a best path in your problem formulation? a path with the shortest number of choice made?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are confusing the A* algorithm with a simple [greedy best-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best-first_search) in which you just compute the heuristic `h(n)` which, in some way, shall estimate the cost (or distance) from the current state to the goal state.

In A* you are expanding nodes that minimize the function `f(n) = g(n) + h(n)` where g(n) provides the (path) cost from the starting point till the current state (and remind that A* can explore more than one direction on the state graph [before finding the optimal one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aAstarExample.gif)).

In your case I can imagine that `g(n)` can equal the length of the path  from the root state since you're interested in the shortest path (and each new state has cost 1). To find an optimal path A*'s h(n) shall never overstimate the optimal solution. For this reason one idea can be to compute it with the number of residual colors in the table (in fact you will always need *at least* that many move to reach the full colored final state).

Note that this heuristic is not that much informative, ie it will have you expand many states before converging to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented an AI for this game which works according to the aforementioned greedy algorithm. In particular, it attempts to maximize the number of cells that would end up being part of the cluster starting at (0,0)

First we define a method that calculates a set of points, that are neighbours of eachother, and have the same color. We'll call this a cluster.

```
def cluster(self, x, y):

    # setup return value
    retval = sets.Set([])

    # stack
    col = self._grid[x][y]
    stk = []
    stk.append((x,y))

    while len(stk) > 0:
        curr = stk.pop()
        retval.add(curr)
        c_x = curr[0]
        c_y = curr[1]

        nbs = [(c_x,c_y+1),(c_x,c_y-1),(c_x+1,c_y),(c_x-1,c_y)]
        for n in nbs:
            if n[0] < self._width and n[0] >=0 and n[1] < self._height and n[1] >= 0:
                if self._grid[n[0]][n[1]] == col and not (n in retval):
                    stk.append(n)   
    # return
    return retval
```

Then we can define flooding the grid as simply taking the cluster of (0,0) and marking those cells with a new color.

```
    def flood(self, x, y, c):
    pts = self.cluster(x,y)
    for p in pts:
        self._grid[p[0]][p[1]] = c
```

The easy (greedy) strategy can then be implemented as follows:

```
    def easy_strategy(self):

    retval = []
    g = copy.deepcopy(self)
    c = g.cluster(0,0)
    S = g._width * g._height

    # continue until all cells have the same color
    while len(c) != S :

        # attempt all flood options
        cps = []
        for i in xrange(0, self._num_colors+1):
            cps.append(copy.deepcopy(g))
        csz = [0 for i in xrange(0, self._num_colors+1)]
        for i in xrange(0,self._num_colors+1):
            cps[i].flood(0,0,i)
            csz[i] = len(cps[i].cluster(0,0))

        # best move     
        max_index = csz.index(np.max(csz))                                  
        g = cps[max_index]
        c = g.cluster(0,0)

        # append to array
        retval.append(max_index)

    # return
    return retval
```

This essentially does the following:
 1. copy the current grid k times (where k is the number of colors)
 2. flood each copy (at index i) with color i
 3. calculate the size of the cluster at (0,0)
 4. select the copy (and corresponding color) for which the cluster is largest

Although this is a naive implementation, it does perform well.

Kind regards,
Joris